# echo after loop finishes rather than while looping

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, echo, forum

I am coding my own forums (for learning reasons) and am trying to find a solution to the following:

I have forum posts stored in the database and when I want to display these posts, I first put each post from mySQL into an array ($posts[][]) then loop through these arrays to output them onto the htmlpage:

```
if (count($posts) > 0) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($posts); $x++) {
        echo '
        <div class="post-header">' . $posts[$x][3] . '<text style="float:right">#' . ($x+1) . '</text></div>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-user ">';
            if(login_check($mysqli) && (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3 || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {
                echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
            }
            echo '<a href="../profile/?profile="' . $posts[$x][5] . '">' . $posts[$x][5] . '</a>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div class="post-text">' . $bbcode->parse($posts[$x][4]) . '</div>
        </div><br>';
    }
}
```

Whilst this runs perfectly fine I wish for the echo to only display after the loop finishes. At the moment this echos in real time and each forum post gets  added in to the html until the loop finishes, which looks like it is loading very slowly.

Comment: Why don't you just store it in a var? and when the loops finish echo that?

Comment: What do you mean by: "which looks like it is loading very slowly"? If you echo in the loop or outside the loop doesn't really matter when it comes to speed. You're still echoing the same amount of data and have the same number of iterations in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
            if (count($posts) > 0) {
                $sexy = '';
                for ($x = 0; $x < count($posts); $x++) {
                    $sexy .='
                    <div class="post-header">' . $posts[$x][3] . '<text style="float:right">#' . ($x+1) . '</text></div>
                    <div class="post">
                        <div class="post-user ">';
                        if(login_check($mysqli) && (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3 || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {
                            $sexy .='<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
                        }
                        $sexy .='<a href="../profile/?profile="' . $posts[$x][5] . '">' . $posts[$x][5] . '</a>
                        <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-text">' . $bbcode->parse($posts[$x][4]) . '</div>
                    </div><br>';
                }
                echo $sexy;
            }
```

This will echo at the end of the loop. But if you recognize slow loading, go for "paging" your results e.g display only 50 per page and show some navigation at the bottom. Another possiblilty to increase responsibility and show everything once it arrives, with flush: http://php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php

Comment: in php + is not the concatanation operator its .(period)

Comment: I currently only have 16 posts on my test page, I do however have paging enabled for a maximum of 25 posts, but it still seems to load slowly (even after adding what @Saurabh Sinha sugested)

Comment: I will create a new question since this one has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
$responseString = '';
if (count($posts) > 0) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($posts); $x++) {
        $responseString .= '
        <div class="post-header">' . $posts[$x][3] . '<text style="float:right">#' . ($x+1) . '</text></div>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-user ">';
            if(login_check($mysqli) && (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3 || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {
                $responseString .= '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
            }
            $responseString .= '<a href="../profile/?profile="' . $posts[$x][5] . '">' . $posts[$x][5] . '</a>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div class="post-text">' . $bbcode->parse($posts[$x][4]) . '</div>
        </div><br>';
    }
}
echo $responseString;
```

Comment: you would simply need to create a variable and instead of using echo you can just assign the value to that variable and keep on appending throughout the loop. Once the loop is done. you can echo the same

Comment: This answers my question perfectly however and @magnus Eriksson stated, whilst this does hold of displaying information until the end (thank you!) I am still experiencing a slow loading. I only 16 posts, with very little text. Should i be adding all the posts into an array before the page even loads then displaying what is required when it's asked for? Sorry for the questions!